# Insert date in mongodb in correct format and query mongodb with date range

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have a date in the format `14-06-2016 12:10:pm` I want to insert the date in **mongodb** in correct format Using **Javascript** so that I can query the date in **php** code like following:

```
$filter = array("order.estdate" => array('$gte' => $_REQUEST['fromdate'], '$lte' => $todate1));
$cursor = $collection->find($filterpatient)->sort(array('_id'=>-1));
```

fromdate will be in "dd-mm-yyyy" format.
 Please help me.

Comment: in what formate your date is saving in databse??

Comment: I want to save in mongodb in correct format so that I can query it. presently I am storing in d-m-Y h:i:a format in mongodb but unable to query the date in a date range from mongodb

Comment: Dates should include a time zone offset, otherwise they represent a different moment in time for each time zone with a different offset.

Comment: How I can convert the date 14-06-2016 12:10:pm into mongodb compatible date format in javascript?

Comment: you can use javascript Date constructor i.e. `new Date()`. You can now query using another date object.

Comment: use the aggregation `$dateToString` while slecting or fetching the records

Comment: @Mike—no, don't do that.

Comment: According to [*the documentation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/Date/), you can pass a Date object directly to the database, where it will be stored as a time value. To correctly parse a string like `14-06-2016 12:10:pm` you'll need to write a small function or use a library and tell it the format. It will be treated as local for the system on which it's parsed.

Comment: I am able to store the record in mongodb like `' "estdate" : "2016-06-14T06:49:00.000Z"` now when I am writing the following php it is not giving any result    `:$from=$start = new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-04-11 00:00:00'));
         echo $to=new MongoDate(strtotime('2016-06-18 00:00:00'));
         $filterpatient = array("order.patientinfo.order_id" => $ordertext,"order.orderitem.estdate" => array('$gte' =>$from, '$lte' => $to));
         $cursor = $collection->find($filterpatient)->sort(array('_id'=>-1));`

Comment: @RobG Thanks, but could you please tell me why I should not do that. Because I have been using it this way in all my projects. If there's another better way, I should start using that.

Comment: @Mike—parsing of strings using the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is largely implementation dependent and inconsistent across implementations. Always parse strings manually. If you only have a single format to deal with, write a small function. Otherwise, use a library (there are plenty of good ones to choose from) and always provide the format to parse.

Comment: @srikantamondal—note that `2016-06-14T06:49:00.000Z` will be parsed as UTC/GMT, but `2016-04-11 00:00:00` will be parsed as local, so will be adjusted for the host system time zone.

Comment: Thanks @RobG for the info.